# Calling Yoast SEO title in widget not work

Tags: php, wordpress

I just install Wordpress SEO plugin by Yoast, test the title re-write function and it works in my title bar (single post). However when I try to call the title in widget, I just get error message

> Warning: Missing argument 1 for kpndg()...

I insert this code in theme functions.php

```
add_filter( 'wpseo_title', 'kpndg' );
function kpndg( $title )  {
    return $title;
}
```

Then call it in my widget:

```
$out.='<div class="trending-bar add-active bar-' . $i . '">';

    $out.='<a class="trending-link" href="'.get_permalink().'">&nbsp;</a>'; 

    $out.='<div class="title">'.kpndg().'</div>';

    $out.='<div class="trending-color-wrapper">';
        $out.='<div class="trending-color-layer"></div>';
        $out.='<div class="trending-color"></div>';
        $out.='<div class="trending-meta">' . $meta . '</div>';
    $out.='</div>';

$out.='</div>';
```

I can't figure out what is the problem in that code.

FYI: I use Engine theme by Industrial Themes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line: `$out.='<div class="title">'.kpndg().'</div>';`

You need to specify an argument... Or, alternatively, set a default value for the `$title` argument:

```
add_filter( 'wpseo_title', 'kpndg' );
function kpndg( $title = 'foo' )  {
    return $title;
}
```

**Edit**

Are you sure you didn't mean to use `get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), '_yoast_wpseo_title', true);` in place of `kpndg()`?

**Edit #2**

Instead of adding a new filter for `wpseo_title`, just create a "helper function":

```
function kpndg() {
  return get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), '_yoast_wpseo_title', true) ?: get_the_title();
}
```

Then, within the loop, you can call `echo kpndg()`

Comment: the results is just `foo` in my widget

Comment: See my edit. Are you sure you want to call `kpndg()` directly?? Otherwise, I'm thinking you meant to call `get_the_title()`

Comment: I want to call the SEO title that created by Yoast SEO plugin. I googling on that and find `wpseo_title` API (CMIIW). So I create new function, then call it in my widget...

Comment: The plugin already applies filters to `the_title()`, though.... so you're trying to do what the plugin is doing.  Try my suggestion.

Comment: Did you mean `$out.='<div class="title">'.get_the_title().'</div>';`? Just tried that, but the result is the original title of the post, not the SEO title.

Comment: Ahh, I forgot - that's not the case. Try this: `get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), '_yoast_wpseo_title', true);` instead.

Comment: `$out.='<div class="title">'.get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), '_yoast_wpseo_title', true);.` Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ... :(

Comment: Oh my fouls... :D Just get it works.. But can we transform `get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), '_yoast_wpseo_title', true);` into a function? than call it like `.kpndg().` to make the code more simple when calling it more than one times in other php file..

Comment: And I think to use `get_the_title()` as default value

Comment: You can, only if `kpndg()` is called while in the loop (otherwise you have to provide ID's). Updated answer